# CLion prints the input back

Tags: clion

Everyone. I've been using CLion for some time and I do like it, except one thing. Maybe somebody had the same problem.

The thing is that when I print something in console, the IDE prints it back. For example, if I run that code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string message;
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
    std::cout << "You've printed: " << message;
    return 0;
}
```

the IDE will act like this:
[Printing back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dca1l.png)

I think that problem lies in CMake, but as a newy I have no idea how to fix it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because getline returns an [istream& parameter](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

Seems like it is a known issue, related to MinGW and bugged in JetBrains tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-2580#u=1443705085694

It is just an issue with IDE / terminal obviously, program will run properly if run outside of the IDE.