# Repeating user input in CLion console

Tags: c++, clion

When I type something In CLion console when my app is reading some data(like `cin`),
 my input is repeated even if app don't write anything to stdout.

For example when i type `6`, I get another `6`, however my app don't write anything.

Why it happens? It's very annoying, so how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using MinGW? Possible answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669359/clion-prints-the-input-back)
. Its a known issue.

Two workarounds are available:

- Turn off PTY: by disabling run.processes.with.pty option in the Registry (Help -> Find Action -> Registry...)
- Use Cygwin64 instead